# Chartjs React Typescript moving x axis labels above chart

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chart.js

I'm using chartjs to generate a bar chart, and one of the requirements is to have the x-axis labels appear at the top of the chart rather than the bottom. (Even though I disagree with this, apparently there is no leeway from the client) and I'm having trouble following the documentation and any examples I find are for older versions.

The relative packages I'm using are:

```
"chart.js": "^3.7.1",
"react-chartjs-2": "^4.0.0",
```

Secondly they want the labels to wrap rather being a single line based on bar width, since it's responsive. I was experimenting with using arrays to break up the words as an example, but wondering if this can be done within chartjs. Here is the code I have setup so far (I had to use some lorem ipsum cause of sensitive data):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  ChartOptions
} from 'chart.js';
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import { Chart } from 'react-chartjs-2';

ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
);

// added as an example. if there is a negative value, the bar color changes.
const generateBgColors = (data : number[]) => {
  const bgColors = [];

  for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const value = data[i];
    if(value > 0) {
      bgColors.push('rgba(53, 162, 235, 0.5)');
    } else {
      bgColors.push('rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)');
    }
  }
  return bgColors;
}

const options =  {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: true,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    }
  },
  scales: {
  }
} 
var data = [2.0, -2.0, 0.5, 1.5];
const labels = [
  ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,', ' consectetur adipiscing elit.', ' Integer eget auctor felis.'],
  ['label2'],
  ['label3'],
  ['label4'],
];
const chartData = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [
    {
      data: [2.0, -2.0, 0.5, 1.5],
      backgroundColor: generateBgColors(data)
    }
  ]
}
const BeliefsChart : React.FunctionComponent = (props) => {
  const chartRef = React.useRef<ChartJS>(null);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Chart type="bar" ref={chartRef} options={options} data={chartData} height={50} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make the labels appear on top in V3 of chart.js you need to specify the position to top in `options.scales.x` like so:

```js
options: {
  scales: {
    x: {
      position: 'top'
    }
  }
}
```

To achieve multi line labels you will need to define your labels array as arrays for the the labels that have to be multi lined. Each entry in the nested arrray will be a new line

```js
labels = ['singel line', ['line 1', 'line 2'], ['line 1', 'line 2', 'line3']]
```

Live Example:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['singel line', ['line 1', 'line 2'], ['line 1', 'line 2', 'line3']],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3],
        backgroundColor: 'orange'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5],
        backgroundColor: 'pink'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        position: 'top'
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies in advance since I'm not familiar with Typescript, but hopefully the following answers will be of help to you regardless.

1. To position the x-axis labels, try adding the following **scales** details to your options:

```
const options =  {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: true,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    }
  },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      position: "top"
    }]
  }
}
```

2. I don't know if it's possible to make the labels wrap, but an alternative responsive solution might be to use a variable for the **fontSize** of the **ticks** (labels) and vary the fontSize value based on the size of the screen using a media query. For example:

```
import { useMediaQuery } from "react-responsive";
```

```
const isMobile = useMediaQuery({ query: '(max-width: 480px)' });
const responsiveFontSize = isMobile ? 12 : 16;

const options =  {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: true,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    }
  },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      position: "top"
    }]
    ticks: {
      fontSize: responsiveFontSize,
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Answer you posted does not work, it is for an outdated version of chart.js that OP is not using